# Acumatica publishing a custom table and custom form on 2020 r2

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

i am trying to update my acumatica version to the latest version 2020 r2 from 2019 r1. as i am publishing my customization project i encountered an error that wont let me continue my publish.

See photo
[image]
this is my error even if i remove all of the customization that create mc9000000 form and its site map reference it still gives me this error. i tried removing all of the things related to this error. i got my customization form my old 2019 r1. and this instance is also a clone of 2019 r1.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Customization package and go to your page and Open Actions.
Remove the records from there if you haven't added them intentionally.

[image]